# How to store private in server safely?

Tags: docker, security, root

I was thinking what is the most secure place to store private data (credentials to DB for example).

I see 2 options:

1. in environment variables
2. in a file

2nd option seems more secure, especially when you set `chmod a-rwx`  on the file and only sudo users can read it.

When we run docker container, the code inside has root access by default.

So what do you think about this idea:

- create a file with empty access (`chmod a-rwx private.txt`)
- run a docker and provide the file to it: `docker run -v=$(pwd):/app  php:7.3-alpine3.9 cat /app/private.txt`
- docker has to be in sudo group

Now, when a hacker break into the server he will not be able to read credentials stored in `private.txt` file. Our program in docker container can read a file. The hacker needs a root access, but with root access he can do whatever he wants.

What do you think about this idea? Is it secure?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to use swarm, you can check Docker's article about "[Manage sensitive data with Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)"

Regarding your secret file, without going into the cons and pros of that method, if your program has an exploitable vulnerability, a hacker could potentially gain access to your files on behalf of the running program, etc.